# d3 React JS: d3.csv is importing index.html instead of csv file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to use the d3-request library in my react App.js file to import and parse data in a .csv file.  When I output the resultant data to the console, it is returning an array of lines from the App.js file instead of from the target csv file. What am I missing?

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {csv} from 'd3-request';
import './App.css';
import Chart from './components/chart'

const API_URL = "https://nataliia-radina.github.io/react-vis-example/";

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
       this.state = {
          results: [],
       };
   }
   render() {
      csv("./data/test.csv", function(error, data) {
         if (error) throw error;
         console.log(data);
       });

      const {results} = this.state;

      return (
         <div className="App">
            <Chart data={results}
             />
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**test.csv**

```
col1,col2,col3
hi,there,buddy
```

**console output**

```
(39) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, columns: Array(1)]
0:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "<html lang="en">"}
1:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "  <head>"}
2:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "    <meta charset="utf-8">"}
3:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"}
4:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">"}
5:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">"}
6:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">"}
7:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "    <title>React App</title>"}
8:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "  </head>"}
9:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "  <body>"}
10:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "    <noscript>"}
11:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."}
12:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "    </noscript>"}
13:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "    <div id="root"></div>"}
14:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></body>"}
15:{<!DOCTYPE html>: "</html>"}
columns:["<!DOCTYPE html>"]
length:39
__proto__:Array(0)
```

Comment: I think it's failing to find the CSV file (i.e. a 404 error) and your server is setup to return the `index.html` file in this case (A common configuration to allow client-side routing). What do you see in the browser console?

Comment: The browser console output is as above in my OP under `console output`.  It shows the index.html file. It makes sense that it's defaulting to index if it can't find my file. But my file is there so I don't understand why it's doing this.

Comment: Are you using D3 v3/4 or D3 v5?

Comment: @dbconfession sorry, I should have been clearer, I meant the "network" tab.

Answer (score 3):

Try importing the data first:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {csv} from 'd3-request';
import './App.css';
import Chart from './components/chart';
import data from './data/test.csv'; 

const API_URL = "https://nataliia-radina.github.io/react-vis-example/";

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
       this.state = {
          results: [],
       };
   }
   render() {
      csv(data, function(error, data) {
         if (error) throw error;
         console.log(data);
       });

      const {results} = this.state;

      return (
         <div className="App">
            <Chart data={results}
             />
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you explain why we need to import first when we can directly use url inside d3.csv(url) ?

Answer (score 1):

csv(url) -- This will send a request to the server to get the file.

> keep this test.csv file in public folder and try accessing it like
>   csv("/test.csv")
>   I have tried and it has worked.

I am not sure about the line number 2, the below import statement of csv worked for me..

> import {csv} from "d3"

Comment: This is the best route to go. You don't need to create a server.

In my situation, I kept the `data.csv` file in react's `public` folder.
Then imported the csv from d3 as a named import, I proceeded to make the call:

>d3.csv('./data.csv').then(data => {
>    console.log(data)
>});

Read more about the `public` folder here - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to keep your csv file in the public folder of the react project.This is the best route to go. **You don't need to create a server.**

In my situation, I kept the `data.csv` file in react's `public` folder.
I proceeded to make the call:

> d3.csv('./data.csv').then(data => console.log(data));

Another option in making this call is to use `%PUBLIC_URL%/data.csv` as indicated on the create-react-app website.
Read more about the `public` folder here - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced something similar, from my testing I have figured out that if something is not served on the server (your .csv file in this case), it re-directs the unknown file path as index.html. I don't know why it does that. I still haven't found the way to serve data inside data folder. One solution is to store the data directly inside the public folder and link it as "*/filename.csv*" or (*process.env.PUBLIC_URL*+"filename.csv") inside a JS file.