# d3.csv() is returning my index.html file instead of the csv file

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I am trying to use d3.csv() to read in my data. When logging my data using console.log(data), instead of returning the contents of the csv, the console is showing each line of my index.html file.

Current code:

```js
import * as d3 from "d3";

d3.csv('/data/nobel_final.csv').then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Output:
[image: Current output]

I installed d3 via npm. I attached my js file in a script tag before the body tag in my html. I have tried using http-server and parcel and both result in the same output. I have tried everthing [in this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242933/d3-react-js-d3-csv-is-importing-index-html-instead-of-csv-file) and still haven't had any luck.

Comment: Are you sure that is not the contents of your nobel_final.csv file?

Comment: Yes, @chackerian, I've confirmed the contents of nobel_final.csv is the data I want to read not what is being logged.

Comment: I had the same first thought that @chackerian did. If you are indeed sure that the CSV contains CSV, rather than HTML, then are you sure that you're pointing to the correct location? Is it really at `/data/nobel_final.csv` or should you be using a relative URL? If you're trying to access a non-existent file via a local server, then you might be fetching the HTML of a does not exist warning.